# ClassCastException: CustomFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment / Using android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an application divided in one library and two applications : 1 for phones, the other for tablets. A lot of code and layout is defined in the library, and only a few parts are defined in the applications.

I'm using fragments in an `Activity`, with a `ViewPager` for the phone version (layout and activity defined in the library, used with no change in the phone application). 
For the tablet version, I want to show my fragments (2) side by side, and not in a `ViewPager`, so I tried to build an XML layout like that :

```
<....>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentsParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/f1"
            android:class="com.test.Fragment1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/f2"
            android:name="com.test.Fragment2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
    </LinearLayout>
</....>
```

My problem is that the code is working on my phone application, but not on my tablet application. On this one, I get this exception stack :

```
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    ... 11 more

07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:535)
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4168)
07-11 17:41:14.032: E/AndroidRuntime(14754):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
```

The error messages talk about `android.app.Fragment` where I Would expect `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

After searching the web, I checked these points :

- My activity extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`,
- My fragments extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`,
- My application uses the support.v4 library.

Comment: Have you tried using thr full support library package name in your XML insrtead of just `Fragment`?

Comment: I can't have access to my code at this moment, but this is something I've tried and, if I remember correctly, a crash occurred too. I'll try again tomorrow and I'll post the exception raised.

Comment: I've tried again, and had this result :

    07-12 09:40:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4503): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be cast to android.view.View

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Nevermind, in my case is was because I didn't call the super class method in my Activity onCreate.

Answer (score 6):

Your Activity have to be extended by FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2):

You probably got wrong (mixed) imports and instad of

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

you have

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

hence the cast issue.

Comment: which is mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html#Apis

Comment: As I have mentioned it in my first message, I have checked this point and I do **NOT** include the android.app.Fragment* packages in my code, I use the packages from the support v4 library...

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this in any way? If not, you should check out your manifest file, if there is an Activity declared with your Fragments name. (if so, remove them)

Comment: An activity declared with my fragments name ? What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean you should check if any of your Fragments are declared in your manifest file as Activities, if it is so -> delete them!

Comment: @Aivan Could you post your layout file, and your activity-fragment connection (also onCreate() and  onCreateView() from your fragment(s) ). -- maybe in a new SO Question

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same exact issue! Please post solution if you resolved...

Comment: @Mike Be sure to check on the correct imports of each Fragment class -> android.support.v4.app.Fragment, don't forget to add the library to your project  (these are true only if you target you application to min-sdk of less than 11(Honeycomb). If you still have problems with it, I'd recommend to update your Android SDK Manager, and just create a new project using the template for ViewPager, so you'd have an example to confront your problem with.

Comment: @Mike Sorry for the delay. I'm not working on this project anymore, but if I remember correctly, I just removed the fragments from the layout, and I added them by code.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came across the same problem, 
in my case calling super.onCreate(Bundle) before setting layout with setContentView(int) solved the ClassCastException